# Executing HTTP Request from Tapestry code

Tags: java, httprequest, task, tapestry

I am wondering what is the best practice for executing a http request from Tapestry code.

Here's a more concrete case:

On successful submit from some form, I'd like to execute a few http get requests to some URLs. Of course, one way to do it is in that method (onSubmitFromSomeForm()), but I don't really want to do that.

I was wondering if the good approach would be to try and implement it like this: http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5HowToRunTaskInThread

I'm running Tapestry 5.3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a simple service that spawns a new thread using [ParallelExecutor](https://tapestry.apache.org/parallel-execution.html).

```
public class CrawlerImpl implements Crawler {

    private final ParallelExecutor executor;

    public CrawlerImpl(final ParallelExecutor executor) {

        this.executor = executor;
    }

    @Override
    public void crawl(final String url) {

        Future<String> future = executor.invoke(new Invokable<String>() { ... });

    }
}
```

Comment: Tyvm, I'll give it a try and accept if it works :)
In the meantime, here's an upvote :)